# What's the relationship between supersaturation and temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, solubility, analytical-chemistry

In gravimetric analysis, what does supersaturation mean? And, how is it achieved by lowering the temperature, even though increasing the temperature makes a higher number of solute particles *more* soluble?

Answer (score 3):

[Supersaturation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersaturation) means simply that more of the substance is dissolved than should be. Supersaturation is an unstable condition. Given some "trigger" precipitation will occur and equilibrium conditions will then be restored.

The trigger could be a seed crystal, scratching a glass rod on a side wall or a piece of dust which acts as a nucleation point.

Comment: So can this trigger be lowering its temperature ?

Comment: Lowering the temperature is used to reach supersaturation in the first place.

Comment: yeah i don't understand how ..isn't it supposed that increasing the temp is needed to reach supersaturation??

Comment: Nope. Increasing the temperature would increase the solubility. You want to _decrease_ it.

Comment: in order to precipitate?

Comment: In order to make the solution supersaturated, and ultimately, yes, to precipitate.

Comment: @SalmaM.Hanafy Whether temperature is increased or decreased, depends on the situation at hand. A good number of solutes will dissolve less if temperature is increased in some range; but decreasing temperature is still more common. Precipitation is usually a slow process, so before you optain an insoluble solid, there is a time period when the concentration exceeds maximum solubility at the particular temperature. Mathematically, relative supersaturation turns positive.

Comment: @SalmaMHanafy Glad we could help!